# WSO2 admin console restriction to localhost

Tags: wso2-esb

I have a question about restricting the Admin Console access in version 4.0.3. I would like the admin console to be accessed only from the server in which WSO2 ESB is installed and not from the machines outside.

In tomcat I can do that using the address attribute of the Connector element in the `server.xml`

like this:

```
Connector port="8080" address="127.0.0.1"
```

The issue is I am not finding the `server.xml` within the 4.0.3 directory strcutre.

I found the file `catalina-server.xml` under `wso2esb-4.5.0/repository/conf/tomcat` in the latest version. I am not finding a similar file within 4.0.3 however.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier it used mgt-transports.xml file for transport configurations in ESB_HOME/repository/conf. After the improvements for tomcat layer by adding it as a proper OSGi bundle in the new release tomcat configurations are offered directly to the user to adjust